# Addition to "Markdown Editing Help" request

Tags: support, markdown, faq-update-request

Under the Markdown Editing Help (MEH) there is a large section on the way Markdown works.
[image]

When recently typing in a path with backslashes `\` and square brackets `[]` some things get eaten. After some discussion on the M.SO tavern, this is not a bug, just part of Markdown's formatting and the way it deals with some characters.

Could I humbly request that the information on [the Backslash markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) can be added to the FaQ or Markdown Editing Help as it is not instantaly obvious if this is a bug or expected behaviour (and if it does exist somewhere on the SE sites please define a suitable punishment).

> \   backslash
>
> `   backtick
>
> ?   asterisk
>
> _ underscore
>
> {}  curly braces
>
> []  square brackets
>
> ()  parentheses
>
> *#   hash mark*
>
> *+   plus sign*
>
> *-   minus sign (hyphen)*
>
> *.   dot*
>
> *!   exclamation mark*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Er.. what?

**Paths should generally be formatted as code.**

Both the inline help (as shown in your screenshot) and [the full editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) both indeed indicate how to format as code, both inline and block.

So either inline with backticks …

`\\computername\folder\filename.txt`

… or as a 4 space indented code block …

```
\\computername\folder\filename.txt
```

… and not entered as plain text:

\computername\folder\filename.txt

Therefore in the screenshot, "code" is the correct help, and is already present.

Comment: so I am being a moron. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @tom no, not at all! merely that we need to make it clear that posting paths is kind of like posting code..

Comment: *chuckle* thanks, if you could do that it would be very useful.